# Ubuntu and Windows 8

Tags: windows

Do you have a version of Ubuntu that works with Windows 8?
Ubuntu 12.04.3 and 13.10 can not detect windows 8 on my hard drive and want to erase everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to free some space on Windows 8 (depending on your needs, like 50 GBs) and install Ubuntu with custom installation and make a second partition